# Redis Unable To Connection From IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linux, iis, redis

I use ASP.NET MVC application and Redis server. The application and Redis server run seperate servers.
And Redis server runs on linux and i can connect to redis server from redis-cli. The web application runs on IIS of course.
I have started to use store session in redis. I install and use "Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider" for this purpose. "Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider.dll" 3.x version runs perfect. But when i upgrade it 4.x version so it raise error. I tried everthing that i know. But the problem has still continue.

```
//Web.config
<modules>
  <remove name="Session" />
  <add name="Session" type="Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModuleAsync, Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</modules>

<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
    <providers>
        <add type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" name="MySessionStateStore" host="WEBSRV01" accessKey="" ssl="false" />
    </providers>
</sessionState>
```

And i take this error already (My redis server runs properly)

> ```
> Server Error in '/' Application. UnableToConnect on
> WEBSRV01:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE,
> origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago,
> last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10
> vailable, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.1.30.38891
> ```

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/issues Consider the project has been idle for months, you really shouldn't upgrade to 4.x.

Comment: I use to nuget for upgrade. Is there any way? I looked this link also. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider    maybe the problem is my redis works on linux and application server is iss.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There was an upgrade problem. I updated dll 's in the web.config and there is no problem now.